# How can I add 3rd party scripts to a gatsby remark based blog?

Tags: gatsby

I have a website that is built using gatsby, and my blog is generated from markdown files parsed with remark.  How can I add third party scripts to the blog posts?  By third party scripts, I mean something like:

```
<script src="https://emgithub.com/embed-v2.js?target=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fedmcman%2Ffuzzyhash-test%2Fblob%2Fmain%2Fexp1%2Foo.gcc.dis&style=base16%2Fsolarized-dark&type=code&showBorder=on&showLineNumbers=on&showFileMeta=on&showFullPath=on&showCopy=on"></script>
```

There are many various plugins that try to solve this problem for specific sites, but there aren't any for emgithub, for example.  I'd thus like to find a solution that works for most scripts.

I've tried changing my blog from remark to `gatsby-mdx`, but v4 seems like a bit of a mess.

I also tried using [remark-rehype](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-rehype) to embed gatsby's [Script](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/) component.  While I was able to embed components, when I embedded Script the embedded script did not appear in the DOM for unknown reasons.